# Is there a way to put an entire part of a request in a SoapUI variable?

Tags: json, rest, testing, groovy, soapui

I'm using SoapUI to test REST webservices and I'm stuck on an issue.

I have a json object, called `coverages`, which consists of **one or more** other objects, it looks something like this (example with 2 coverages):

```
"coverages" : [
   {
   "CovNr" : 123,
   "CovDesc" : "My coverage" 
   },
   {
   "CovNr" : 456,
   "CovDesc" : "Another coverage"
   }
]
```

The thing is, sometimes there is one coverage, and sometimes there are multiple. This  means I need the coverages object to be variable, and have either one or more coverages as its body, depending on # of coverages.

Since the number of coverages isn't always the same I can't use properties for the `CovNr` and `CovDesc` attributes. Also I can't just always add like three and leave two empty if only one is used (can't have empty attributes).

I tried to set a coverages property using groovy script, which consisted of the entire body of the coverages object, but that didn't work (I'm guessing the editor can't parse an entire part of a request from a property).

Example of what I tried:

*in groovy:*

```
def coverages = '''[   {   "CovNr" : 123,   "CovDesc" : "My coverage"    },   {   "CovNr" :456,   "CovDesc" : "Another coverage"   }]'''
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("coverages", coverages)
```

*in request body:*

```
...
"coverages" : "${#TestCase#coverages}",
...
```

This didn't work.

Is there another way to add a variable number of coverages to my request body?

Comment: Try with `"${#TestCase#coverages}"`

Comment: @ou_ryperd oh yeah thanks, that is actually what I tried. I'll edit the post. But that didn't work.